# Calling functions with exec instead of select

Tags: postgresql, psql

Is the default way of calling a function `select * from my_function()`?

I ask because I have built a function that doesn't return anything, just inserts data into a table and (coming from a SQL Server background) it "feels" strange to call it with `select * from...`

I was expecting something like `exec my_function()`

Answer (score 68, accepted):

use `PERFORM` statement - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-statements.html

> Sometimes it is useful to evaluate an expression or SELECT query but
>   discard the result, for example when calling a function that has
>   side-effects but no useful result value. To do this in PL/pgSQL, use
>   the PERFORM statement

so it's just

```
DO $$ BEGIN
    PERFORM my_function();
END $$;
```

Comment: `PERFORM` is only valid within PL/PgSQL. You can't use it stand-alone.

Comment: yes, it should be executed inside the PL/PgSQL block or in function, updated

Answer (score 38):

## PostgreSQL 11:

PostgreSQL 11 [supports true stored procedures](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createprocedure.html) as pointed out by @AbdisamadKhalif . They support in-procedure transaction control.

## Older versions:

Yes, that's the standard way, and yes it's weird.

Usually you'd write such functions as *stored procedures* and invoke them with the `CALL` or `EXECUTE` command. PostgreSQL does not support true stored procedures (multiple result sets, autonomous transactions, and all that) though, only *sql-callable user-defined functions*.

So the workaround is to `SELECT function_name()` using the PostgreSQL extension syntax that omits `FROM`, or `SELECT 1 FROM function_name();` to be (somewhat) more standard.

The ODBC driver, JDBC driver, etc understand the `{call func_name()}` escape syntax and automatically translate it to an underlying `SELECT`.

Comment: Now PostgreSQL 11 supports Stored Procedures https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createprocedure.html

Comment: @AbdisamadKhalif Updated, thanks for the reminder. It's hard to maintain things.

Answer (score 28):

You will use `from` when the function returns a set. If the function returns `void` just do

```
select my_function();
```